# Can the compiler optimize away ToString() on a string?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

I'm sure everyone's encountered their share of developers who **love** the `ToString()` method.  We've all likely seen code similar to the following:

```
public static bool CompareIfAnyMatchesOrHasEmpty(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
    bool result = false;
    foreach (string item1 in list1)
    {
        foreach (string item2 in list2)
        {
            if (item1.ToString() == item2.ToString())
            {
                result = true;
            }
            if (item1.ToString() == "")
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

What I'm wondering is if the `ToString()` method (the empty, no formatting one) can be optimized away by the compiler?  My assumption is that it does not, since it's originally defined on `object`. Thus I provide this second question, on if any effort to cleanup such instances would be worthwhile?

Comment: That code just sent shivers down my spine!

Comment: _be optimized away_ is hardly relevant, it's too simpel an operation. This is an issue of code quality, not of performance.

Comment: You'd be better served optimizing away the developer who wrote this.

Comment: By the way, is this *real* code? I've got other problem besides the ToString. Like the fact that the runtime is O(M*N) because there are no breaks or return statements...

Comment: Note to all: the above is contrived code, near (but not quite) the worst of what I've seen. The question was inspired by [this TheDailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Too-Much-of-a-Bad-Thing.aspx) which brought back too many bad memories.

Comment: I've seen plenty of `"string constant".ToString()` and even formatting a Decimal to money string, then attempting to parse that as an int, then calling ToString() again, and was asked honestly why it was raising an exception. Also, I suppose that using `.ToString()` willy-nilly on every string will "allow" you to get more `NullReferenceException`s...

Comment: @HenkHolterman In review, I think ultimately your comment "This is an issue of code quality, not of performance." is the most accurate answer, here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It certainly *could* be optimized away by the compiler, but they probably *don't* because it's trivial. Before deciding whether any optimization is worthwhile, try some tests first. Let's try it!

```
List<string> strings = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000000).Select(x => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();
var sw= Stopwatch.StartNew();

foreach (var str in strings) {
    if (!str.ToString().Equals(str.ToString())) {
        throw new ApplicationException("The world is ending");
    }
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Took: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
foreach (var str in strings) {
    if (!str.Equals(str)) {
        throw new ApplicationException("The world is ending");
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Took: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Ok, so we're in a loop with 10 million items. How long does the tostring (called twice) version take compared to the non tostring version?

Here's what I get on my machine:

```
Took: 261.6189 
Took: 231.2615
```

So, yeah. I saved 30 whole milliseconds over 10 million iterations. So...yeah, I'm going to say no, not worth it. At all.

Now, should the code be changed because it's *stupid*? Yes. I would make the argument as, "This is unnecessary and makes me think at a glance that this is NOT a string. It takes me brain cycles to process, and serves literally no purpose. Don't do it." Don't argue from an optimization point of view.

Comment: Always state how you ran a benchmark. Release build, outside VS? This one should also be run with the other loop first.

Comment: Why should the other loop be run first? In any case: Release build, outside VS:
Took: 229.8982
Took: 187.611 

I ran it with the loops switched, and the results were darn near identical. I'm curious why you think it should matter?

Answer (score 8):

The C# compiler will not optimize this away.  However, at runtime, I believe this will likely get inlined by the JIT compiler in the CLR, as `string.ToString()` just returns itself.

`String.ToString` is even declared with `TargetedPatchingOptOutAttribute`, which allows it to be inlined by NGEN as well when it's called from other assemblies, so it's obviously an inline target.

Comment: Then it's optimized away by _a_ compiler.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes - the C# compiler won't, but the JIT will.

Comment: I'm interested in `TargetedPatchingOptOutAttribute`. Could someone include a "dummy's guide" to what "inlined across Native Image Generator (NGen) images" as part of this answer?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie If you use NGEN, it won't (normally) inline calls that cross assembly boundaries - otherwise, an updated mscorlib would change the behavior.  This attribute allows that to be inlined anyways.

Comment: Really torn accepting answers here, so wanted to comment. Appreciate your answer - it did answer the title of the question, and I learned something new. However, I went with aquinas' answer because I think it addressed the heart of the real issue, namely in his last paragraph.